# How do I get the current URL and then get the last words

Tags: php

I want to get the url I'm on and then get what's after the =

For example if I were on:
http://chusmix.com/?s=pizza

It should echo pizza

Comment: `$_GET['s']` is no good?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called a query string and can be retrieved via the $_GET associative array.

```
$_GET["s"]
```