# How can I capture/pass a keyword through a URL and pass it to a PHP page

Tags: php, html, forms, url, get

I'm looking to pass a keyword from a HTML page to a PHP page through the URL string. 
**See example below to what I'm saying:**

mysite.com/index.html?keyword=Google

the "*Keyword*" is **Google** and it needs to go over to my Thank you page.

mysite.com/thankyou.php

the code I use on my "thankyou" page is:

```
<?php $id = $_GET['keyword']; echo $id;?>
```

**NOTE:** I've visited and tried the links I found on the stackflow site... but none of them seem to work (asleast from what I've done with them). Am I missing any other thing when it comes to the code?

[How do I get the current URL and then get the last words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418831/how-do-i-get-the-current-url-and-then-get-the-last-words)

[how can i get the url if it is like this <keyword>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355687/how-can-i-get-the-url-if-it-is-like-this-keyword)

[How to pass a keyword from URL but keep it hidden? (Adwords)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022603/how-to-pass-a-keyword-from-url-but-keep-it-hidden-adwords)

**If you could PLEASE provide a functioning example on a http://jsfiddle.net page so I can see how it works.**

Comment: JSFiddle is for javascript. So how do you suppose we write a functioning example using it?

Comment: In order to do so the php file must be called with the query variable, unless its in session (cookies may work, too.)

Comment: @Kristian thanks... I just realized the JSFiddle was only for javascript. if there is a similar site the could show an example that would work too...

Comment: @RiverC would you happen to know of an example that would show this "query variable" you speak of..?

Comment: @pixelpusheer see the first answer.

Comment: @pixelpusher first, when you want to know something like that, just google it. ;) secondly, an online php sandbox probably wont help you solve your particular question because it relies on setting a url parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the get variable on the php page url, not the index.html page.

Example:
mysite.com/thankyou.php?keyword=Google

Comment: Option #2 is to cookie it with JS. And grab it out from the cookies in the script.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could write a html `<form>` and make a `<input type="hidden" name="keyword" value="Google">` and grab it from POST instead of GET with PHP.

```
<?php $id = $_POST['keyword']; ?>
```